# Which C# language feature allows initializing a property that only provides a get implementation?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I'm working with the System.Text.Json serializer, and need to provide custom serialization logic for one property of my overall object. That's not the issue, it's working, but I don't understand how. This is the sample provided in the MS docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#registration-sample---converters-collection

```cs
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Converters =
    {
        new DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter()
    }
};

jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, serializeOptions);
```

Best I can tell, the Converters property only implements a getter.

[image: Hover description in VSCode]

Here's the decompiled code I get with a Go To Definition.

```cs
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the list of user-defined converters that were registered.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The list of custom converters.
        public IList<Serialization.JsonConverter> Converters { get; }
```

And, what I think is the original code.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.cs#L23

What magick explains this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [collection initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization).

`Converters` is a collection. In the following code:

```
Converters =
{
    new DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter()
}
```

You're not assigning to `Converters` itself. Since the type of `Converters` is a type that implements `IEnumerable` and has an `Add` method with the appropriate signature, the compiler simply generates code that calls that `Add` method and passes it your `DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter` instance. The `Converters` property itself does not need a setter because you only need the collection itself.

The fact that it looks like assignment is just a quirk of the grammar.

Answer (score 2):

It's being done through the [collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements IEnumerable and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance method or an extension method. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression, or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer, you do not have to specify multiple calls; the compiler adds the calls automatically.

While the property itself has only a getter. The instance behind the getter implements `IEnumerable<T>` and also has an `.Add()` method.

So your code is just syntactic sugar for something like this:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions;
serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a basic [Collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers).

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements IEnumerable and has Add with the appropriate signature as an instance method or an extension method. The element initializers can be a simple value, an expression, or an object initializer. By using a collection initializer, you do not have to specify multiple calls; the compiler adds the calls automatically.

```cs
var names = new List<string> {
    "Alice", "Bob", "Curtis", "David"
};

// Equivalent to

var names = new List<string>();
names.Add("Alice");
names.Add("Bob");
names.Add("Curtis");
names.Add("David");
```

It's possible to use on [get only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers-with-collection-read-only-property-initialization) :

```
public class Book
{
    public IList<string> Names { get; } = new List<string> { "Alice", "Bob" };
}


var book = new Book {
    Names = { "Curtis", "David" }
};

// Equivalent to
var book = new Book();
book.Names.Add("Curtis");
book.Names.Add("David");
```